# Scope difference between g++4.9.4 and g++5.4.0

Tags: c++, scope, compiler-errors, g++

The following code compiles fine under g++4.9.4

```
template <typename T>
class C{
  template <typename S>
  friend C fun(S &s){C d; return d;}};

int main(){
  int a = 0;
  C<double> b = fun<int>(a);
  return 0;}
```

However, it fails to compile under g++5.4.0 :

```
main.cpp:8:27: error: 'fun' was not declared in this scope
   C<double> b = fun<int>(a);
                           ^
main.cpp:8:27: note: suggested alternative:
main.cpp:4:12: note:   'fun'
   friend C fun(S &s) {C d;return d;}};
            ^
main.cpp:8:27: error: insufficient contextual information to determine type
   C<double> b = fun<int>(a);
```

I believe that I understand the scope issue is that the friend function doesn't have a scope and the compiler can't determine the correct type for the return class C.  Moreover, the line C < double > isn't enough to determine the type of C.  One way to correct this is as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class C{
  template <typename S>
  friend C fun(S &s,C &c) {C d;return d;}};

template<typename T,typename S>
C<T> fun(S s){
  C<T> d;
  return fun<S>(s,d);}

int main(){
  int a = 0;
  C<double> b = fun<double,int>(a);
  return 0;}
```

I have two questions regarding this:

1. What/why is there a difference in behavior between the two versions of g++?  In other words, what changed?
2. Is there a better way to recover the behavior under g++4.9.4 when working with g++5.4.0?

Comment: A friend function defined and declared only in a class is invisible outside the class definition. The only way to make it visible without one more declaration of it outside the class is to use ADL.

Comment: You can just declare the friend function in the class and define it outside the class. Or define it in the class and declare it one more outside the class.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow This is, likely, a silly question, but since the return type is a templated class, what is the proper syntax for defining it outside the class?

Comment: Your friend function has two parameters but you are trying to call it with one argument are you?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes (essentially).  I'm assuming that g++4.9.4 looked to the left of the equals sign! to determine the remaining parameter.